# How does duqu implement its dll files in PNF file format?

Tags: windows, malware, duqu

As you know files with PNF extension are associated with bitmap file type, from  technically point of view how did authors of duqu implement this? as I concluded it is possible to make dlls in any file format, am I right?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question, but you can load a DLL with any extension so long as the internal structure is in the PE format.

Answer (score 5):

As SteveS said in the comments, Windows doesn't care what file name you use - it's just a label. The "file extension" is only used as an indicator for how a user can interact with the file. Many applications also use it as a way to indicate that the file is of a particular type, but ultimately it's nothing more than a naming convention and shouldn't be relied on.

As long as the file is a [PE format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) module, it can be loaded into a process as a module, e.g. via `kernel32.dll!LoadLibrary`. In fact, Windows relies on this behaviour in many cases, since .exe, .dll, .cpl, .ocx, .sys, .scr and .drv files are all PE files.